# Typo in email notifications (tag subscriptions)

Tags: bug, email-notification

The plaintext part of the tag subscription eMails contains the following text (slightly redacted):

```
[Unsubscribe from this
filter](<http://stackexchange.com/email/unsubscribe-filter/x/x?code=x>) or
change your email preferences by visitingyour [filter subscriptions page
on stackexchange.com](<http://stackexchange.com/users/x?tab=subscriptions>).
```

There is a space missing in `visitingyour`. The HTML version is correct.